# Lightning-input type text should not accept numbers in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

HTML template

```
<lightning-input  type="text" label="Numeric value"  pattern="[0-9]*"></lightning-input>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you try `type="number"` ?

Comment: I think the question is how to allow text input to store everything except numbers.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19715303/regex-that-accepts-only-numbers-0-9-and-no-characters

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** You can use change handler to stop entry of numbers completely.

```
<lightning-input data-entry name="input1" label="Enter Something (Try Numbers)" onchange={handleChange}>
    </lightning-input>
```

JS:

```
handleChange(event){
    let entry = event.target.value;
    let lastChar = entry.slice(-1);
    console.log(entry, entry.slice(0,-1), lastChar, isFinite(lastChar));
    if(isFinite(lastChar)) {
        this.template.querySelector('[data-entry]').value = entry.slice(0,-1);
    }
}
```

**Option 2:** If you want to allow entry but show error and make the input invalid:

```
<lightning-input label="Show Error If Number Is Entered" pattern="^([^0-9]*)$" message-when-pattern-mismatch="Numbers are not allowed"></lightning-input>
```

Here is the [playground link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/wODC563M2/1/edit) with examples.

Comment: Hey i want to stop alphabets not numbers

Comment: Your questions are really confusing, probably you should relook the whole question and go through it twice before posting as many people try to help others in community

Comment: by Your Option 1 it is preventing me to enter the numbers but i want to prevent the alpabets to be enter

Comment: @Areeb please read [how to ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) then [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/284947/edit) your question to correct it. As it stands it is poorly stated as "should not accept numbers" for what you actually wanted. Salesforce-sas answered your question, not what you meant to ask.

Comment: lwc is allowing "etkbm" these alphabets in to lightening-input though we have set number ,pattern as numbers only......How to restrict that alphabets as well?

Answer (score 0):

That should work

```
 <lightning-input type="text" label="Not numeric value" pattern="^([^0-9]*)$" message-when-pattern-mismatch="Numbers are not allowed"></lightning-input>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use this pattern to deny any kind of number `^(0-9)`. ^ is the negate and the following block indicates what isn't valid.